# ListView separator based on date

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

My ListView has alot of rows with a datestamp on them, and what I wanna do is somehow add a very clear separator between weeks, for example a 4px colored line between the rows to indicate where next week begins (IE: Between last row of Sunday, and first row of Monday next week).

Since it seems all but impossible to find any example of this, I'm starting to think it's not that trivial?

Comment: IMO you have to create your own control based on a `ListView` or `Selector`. Another way would be to use groups but that ( I think ) will require creating some styles for group separators.

Comment: Can you use a datagridview instead? Its `Rows` have a `DividerHeight` property (pixels int). You could easily iterate over the rows and set that value to 4.

Comment: @LocEngineer Thanks for the suggestion, but the application is already way too invested around a Listview control to change it out now.

Comment: @MasoudMokhtari don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok. Thanks for remembering that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by identifying entries with a new week compared to the previous entry. One way to do this would be my writing a comparer that compares the date of a previous entry with the date of a current entry:

```
public class WeekComparer : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Bad values");
        }
        var prev = values[0] as DateTime?;

        // first entry has no predecessor, so the predecessor is not a different week
        if (!prev.HasValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var dt1 = prev.Value;
        var dt2 = (DateTime)values[1];

        if (Math.Abs((dt1 - dt2).Days) > 7)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // assume monday to be the first day of week
        var dow1 = (dt1.DayOfWeek + 7 - DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7;
        var dow2 = (dt2.DayOfWeek + 7 - DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7;
        var result = (dow1 < dow2) == (dt1 < dt2);
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note this comparer is potentially incomplete. It might be necessary to cut of the `Time` portion before computing the `Timespan.Days` for comparison.

Then you can use the `ListViewItem.Style` with a `Trigger` on the result of `WeekComparer`. Use `RelativeSource PreviousData` to get the previous item value for comparison with the current item:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:WeekComparer x:Key="sameWeekComparer"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="lv1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="False">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource sameWeekComparer}">
                                <Binding Path="MyDate" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource PreviousData}"/>
                                <Binding Path="MyDate"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 4 0 0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gv1">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MyDate}" Header="MyDate"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This will paint a row where the date is in a different week from the previous rows date with `Red` `BorderBrush` and a `BorderThickness` that draws the border only above the item. You can apply any other kind of style change within the `Trigger`.

Consider the Grid to be the content of some window. I tested with the following data:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<MyDateVM> items = new List<MyDateVM>();

        items.Add(new MyDateVM { Name = "Test 1", MyDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31) }); // first entry
        items.Add(new MyDateVM { Name = "Test 2", MyDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 6) }); // same week as end of december 2018
        items.Add(new MyDateVM { Name = "Test 3", MyDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 3) }); // changed order of date
        items.Add(new MyDateVM { Name = "Test 4", MyDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 9) }); // new week
        items.Add(new MyDateVM { Name = "Test 5", MyDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 10) }); // long gap, new week

        grid1.DataContext = items;
    }
}
```

`MyDateVM` is just a plain data class to store the item properties.

Comment: That worked brilliantly with some modification... I did "var result = (dow2 < dow1) == (dt2 < dt1);" instead of your version! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AndreasAndersson I didn't check all the nitty details, so it's perfectly possible that some edge cases need to be handled differently. Good to hear that the general approach worked for you.

Comment: @AndreasAndersson I think the problem you handled is related to different times of the same day. As long as your date values are sorted (always ascending) your workaround will be good, but if they are sorted differently, then the workaround will fall apart. Better start calculating with pure date values at an early stage: `var dt1 = prev.Value.Date; var dt2 = ((DateTime)values[1]).Date;`

Comment: I will fiddle around with it and see how it works. At the moment everything is always sorted in ascending order, but as you point out, that might change, so thank you again for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of simple ways to achieve this:

You could utilise the `ListViewGroupCollection` within the `ListView`.

e.g:

```
MyListview.Group[0].Items.Add(TheItem);
```

Groups can be added in the Designer View (right-click and Edit Groups etc).

Alternatively you could also add a dummy row as a separator and override the colours and appearance (`TheItem.BackgroundColor = xxx`).

Answer (score 0):

First, have each object return which week they fall into. I googled this, so might need alteration.

```
public property int WeekNumber { get { return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear( SomeDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday); } }
```

Next add a group style to your resources. This controls how it looks. I put mine in the UserControl/Window:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateSeparator">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Reference that style in your ListView:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DateSeparator}" />
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Lastly, in code, grab its default collection and set its grouping property:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( YourBoundList );
view.GroupDescriptions.Add( new PropertyGroupDescription( "WeekNumber" ) );
```

Setting the grouping can also be done from XAML instead of code:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedDataSource" Source="{Binding YourBoundList}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="WeekNumber" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedDataSource}" ...></ListView>
```

I prefer to set this up in code as then I can manipulate the filtering, sorting, and/or grouping to my liking at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, this approach also seems interesting. I haven't tried it out yet, but I will later on this week!